# Bootstrap Accordion - Closing other panels when the intend is to open it's current panel

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to create an accordion with Bootstrap. My intent is to click on a title and have it open and close the panel without having other panels be affected.

In this situation, when I have panels 1 and 2/3 open and click to close 2 or 3, panel 1 ends up closing when it should not be affected at all.

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
```

```html
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!--  Experience  -->
    <section class="container experience">
        <div class="row">
            <h2>Heading</h2>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <span>lorem </span>
            </div>
            <!-- end of 1st column -->

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                <h3 class="panel-title">Title1</h3>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <!-- end of panel title -->

                        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                              </ul>
                            </div>
                            <!-- end of panel body -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- end of panel collapse -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of panel default -->
                </div>
                <!-- end of accordion -->
            </div>
            <!-- end of middle column -->

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <span>blah</span>
            </div>
            <!-- end of 3rd column -->
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <span>lorem</span>
            </div>
            <!-- end of 1st column -->

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">Title2</h3>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of panel title -->

                    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <ul>
                               <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!-- end of panel body -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of panel collapse -->
                </div>
                <!-- end of panel default -->
            </div>
            <!-- end of middle column -->

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <span>lorem</span>
            </div>
            <!-- end of 3rd column -->
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <span>lorem</span>
            </div>
            <!-- end of 1st column -->

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">Title3</h3>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of panel title -->

                    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <ul>
                                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>                                                             </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!-- end of panel body -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of panel collapse -->
                </div>
                <!-- end of panel default -->
            </div>
            <!-- end of middle column -->

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <span>lorem</span>
            </div>
            <!-- end of 3rd column -->
        </div>


    </section>
    <!--    end of experience    -->
```

Also, how do I have the accordions closed by default when page loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `data-parent` attribute to disconnect them from one another and remove `in` `from class="panel-collapse collapse"` if you want them to start off closed.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Experience -->
<section class="container experience">
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Heading</h2>

    <div class="col-md-3"> <span>lorem </span>

    </div>
    <!-- end of 1st column -->
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
              <h3 class="panel-title">Title1</h3>
            </a>

          </div>
          <!-- end of panel title -->
          <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <ul>
                <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- end of panel body -->
          </div>
          <!-- end of panel collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- end of panel default -->
      </div>
      <!-- end of accordion -->
    </div>
    <!-- end of middle column -->
    <div class="col-md-3"> <span>blah</span>

    </div>
    <!-- end of 3rd column -->
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"> <span>lorem</span>

    </div>
    <!-- end of 1st column -->
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
          <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Title2</h3>
          </a>

        </div>
        <!-- end of panel title -->
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <ul>
              <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!-- end of panel body -->
        </div>
        <!-- end of panel collapse -->
      </div>
      <!-- end of panel default -->
    </div>
    <!-- end of middle column -->
    <div class="col-md-3"> <span>lorem</span>

    </div>
    <!-- end of 3rd column -->
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"> <span>lorem</span>

    </div>
    <!-- end of 1st column -->
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
          <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseThree">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Title3</h3>
          </a>

        </div>
        <!-- end of panel title -->
        <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <ul>
              <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!-- end of panel body -->
        </div>
        <!-- end of panel collapse -->
      </div>
      <!-- end of panel default -->
    </div>
    <!-- end of middle column -->
    <div class="col-md-3"> <span>lorem</span>

    </div>
    <!-- end of 3rd column -->
  </div>
</section>
<!-- end of experience -->
```

Comment: Thanks, glad I could help!